Chrome Notification Not Showing Message or Handling Buttons Correctly on macOS
I'm developing a Chrome extension using Manifest V3 and using chrome.notifications.create to show notifications to the user. However, I'm facing a couple of issues on macOS:

The notification only displays the title, not the message.
An unwanted 'Settings' button appears in the options, which I didn't add, and it doesn't respond when clicked.

Here's the code snippet that creates the notification:
chrome.notifications.create({
    type: 'basic',
    iconUrl: '/images/icon16.png',
    title: 'Download Notice',
    message: 'You have previously downloaded this file. Do you want to download it again?',
    buttons: [
        {title: 'Yes'},
        {title: 'No'}
    ],
    requireInteraction: true
}, (notificationId) => {
    // Callback code...
});

I have included "notifications" under permissions in my manifest.json and tried shortening the message text, but it still doesn't show up. This is how the notification appears:

My questions are:

How can I ensure that the message text is displayed in the notification?
Is there a way to remove or configure the 'Settings' button that appears in the notification options to link to the extension settings page?
Are these issues specific to macOS, or are they present in other operating systems as well?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Assuming you've reloaded the extension in chrome://extensions page, it's either a bug in Chrome or a limitation of MacOS because there are no such issues in other platforms.
